# Is it possible to have Rows in a Menu?

Tags: scripting, interface

When making a menu, everytime you add an item to the layout, is added with the same behaviour as `layout.column()` (new elements are added in a column).

I'd like to achieve the result of the (bottom of this) image; having a row per item to display different variables:

[image]

However, when I make a new row() item for each iteration in my loop, I get weird results, with elements displaced.

I wasn't able to see any information about this in the manual, so I don't know if I just have to guess that it may not be possible to do what I want.

So my question; is it possible? (If so, how?)

If not, is there any alternative to accomplish my goal?

Thank you so much for the help.